# data-bind if statement on click function in knockout js

Tags: if-statement, knockout.js, data-binding

I need help on executing an one-liner if statement on my data-bind

**this is the HTML**

```
<div data-bind="text: Fields.FieldDescription, click:function() { $root.selectedToListRule.push(Fields.FieldCode());}" onmousedown="this.style.backgroundColor='#4BA6FF'"></div>
```

**this is the js code**

```
var RemovefieldCodeRule = function (parent, data) {
        //console.log(parent.InitiatorFields(), data.selectedApproverFields());
        var sel = selectedToListRule();
        //console.log(sel);
        for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
            var selCat = sel[i];
            var result = data.selectedApproverFields.remove(function (item) {
                return item.FieldCode() == selCat;
            });
            if (result && result.length > 0) {
                //Add to WorkflowObject - InitiatorFields  
                var obj = dataservice.getEmptyObjects("WorkFlowObjectFields");
                obj.done(function (data) {
                    var wfo = model.genericObject(data);
                    wfo.ID(result[0].ID);
                    wfo.WorkFlowObjects_ID(parent.ID());
                    wfo.FieldCode(result[0].FieldCode());
                    wfo.FieldDescription(result[0].FieldDescription());
                    parent.InitiatorFields.push(wfo);
                });
            }
        }
        selectedToListRule.removeAll();
        parent.InitiatorFields.sort(function (left, right) { return left.FieldDescription() == right.FieldDescription() ? 0 : (left.FieldDescription() < right.FieldDescription() ? -1 : 1) });
        data.selectedApproverFields.sort(function (left, right) { return left.FieldDescription() == right.FieldDescription() ? 0 : (left.FieldDescription() < right.FieldDescription() ? -1 : 1) });

    }
```

on my data-bind, there's a click event wherein i will need to select from the dynamically generated div. what i want to happen is when the user clicks on a certain div (it gets selected) and if the user changes his mind to unselect the div he previously selected.

How can i can achieve this on one-liner if statement using knockout

Comment: have you tried the css binding to apply the class for selected div and then remove it based on an observable which contains some identification about the current selected div...

Comment: @nhoyti as you rows are dynamically generated you can toggle the selection(when clicked you can update a observable say `self.toggleSelect(!self.toggleSelect())` & use the value in `css` binding .Note: toggleSelect observable should be row specific i.e preferebly comes from array you are looping.

Comment: @supercool thank you!